# My Android Tablet Cannot detect by Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, hardware

My Android Tablet Cannot detect by Eclipse even i enable the USB Debugging. My tablet is Hug tablet ICS.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to find the right ADB driver. If this still doesn't work, you should try to put the vendor-id (in the form `0x????`, for example `0x1aca` for Pidion) into the file **adb_usb.ini** in the `.android` directory.

Each vendor-id has to be on a new line.

The .android directory is in your users home directory (windows), if you didn't modify it in your android sdk.

If you are using the android eclipse-download-bundle it may as well be in your androidSDK-driectory.